# Build python-mysqlclient against mariadb-connector-c

Tags: python, mariadb, mysql-python, libmysql

I am trying to compile [python-mysqlclient](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python) against [mariadb-connector-c](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-connector-c) in a Conda environment.  That means that the install prefix is not `/usr/local` but, for example, `$HOME/conda/envs/test`.  I also want to use the `auth_gssapi_client.so` plugin.

Both packages build, but `import MySQLdb` raises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/test_tmp/run_test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: libmariadb.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The reason for this is that *mysqlclient* only searches `lib/` but not
`lib/mariadb` even though it was configured with the right path and sucessfully
built.  I can work around this issue by copying the `*.so` files to `lib/` (or
by creating a symlink), but then, it does not find the GSSAPI plugisn …

I build *mariadb-connector-c 3.0.2* this way:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
make install
```

I can install it and run `mariadb_config` which gives this output:

```bash
Copyright 2011-2015 MariaDB Corporation AB
Get compiler flags for using the MariaDB Connector/C.
Usage: /opt/emsconda/conda-bld/mysqlclient_1510048680472/_h_env/bin/mariadb_config [OPTIONS]
  --cflags        [-I/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/include/mariadb -I/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/include/mariadb/mysql]
  --include       [-I/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/include/mariadb -I/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/include/mariadb/mysql]
  --libs          [-L/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/lib/mariadb/ -lmariadb -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto]
  --libs_r        [-L/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/lib/mariadb/ -lmariadb -lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto]
  --libs_sys      [-lpthread -ldl -lm -lssl -lcrypto]
  --version       [10.2.6]
  --socket        [/tmp/mysql.sock]
  --port          [3306]
  --plugindir     [/opt/emsconda/conda-bld/env/lib/mariadb/plugin]
  --tlsinfo       [OpenSSL 1.0.2k]
```

I then build *python-mysqlclient 1.3.12* this way:

```bash
MYSQL_CONFIG="$PREFIX/bin/mariadb_config"
echo "mysql_config = $PREFIX/bin/mariadb_config" >> site.cfg
$PYTHON -m pip install -I --no-deps .
```

There are two possible solutions for this problem:

1. Configure *mariadb-connector-c* to directly put its stuff into `lib/` – I have not found documentation on how to do this.
2. Make *python-mysqlclient* respect the paths that `mariadb_config` returns – How?

Comment: Have you tried using [addsitedir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.addsitedir)?

Comment: Does this help with finding C-libraries?

Comment: It adds a directory to `sys.path` and process its `.pth` files by default; maybe your problem is that the path of your `so` file isn't listed in `sys.path`, so python modules can't find its reference.

Comment: I don’t think this will help.  python-mysqlclient does find's the `.so` if it is in `lib/`, but this path is also not in `sys.path`.

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX -DINSTALL_LIBDIR=lib -DINSTALL_PLUGINDIR=lib/plugin -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..` partially solves the problem. mysqlclient now finds the lib, but still not the plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to statically link the gssapi stuff into *mariadb-connector-c* and Python *mysqlclient* will work.

This is how to build *mariadb-connector-c:*

```
mkdir build
cd build

cmake \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PREFIX \
    -DINSTALL_LIBDIR=lib \
    -DINSTALL_PLUGINDIR=lib/plugin \
    -DWITH_MYSQLCOMPAT=ON \
    -DAUTH_GSSAPI=STATIC \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    ..

make
make install

# WITH_MYSQLCOMPAT only creates links for the libs, not for the binary:
cd $PREFIX/bin
ln -s mariadb_config mysql_config
```